# Why is this save dialog appearing for some users of Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, savefiledialog

For some users of Internet Explorer 11, when they click our download link, they get this dialog:

[image]

For other users of Internet Explorer 11, when they click our download link, they get this dialog instead:

[image]

It is the same file.  Everyone tested is running IE 11 and Windows 7.  I am not sure if it is a group policy setting or some IE setting.  I would like everyone to get the toast style popup (the second screenshot).

Any suggestions on what setting I can change on the users computer so that they all get the toast style popup?

Comment: Are you able to inspect the response headers of both scenarios? I would be curious where (or if) they differ from one another. Also, does your link invoke any scripting, or does it merely point to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue**:
Applications on the system can register in process COM objects to handle particular file types. At least some older versions of Office products did this. In this case you'll get the first dialog you have a screenshot of instead of the gold bar prompt in your second screenshot. Without more information I speculate that on your two different PCs you may have different versions of Office installed or Office configured differently or in IE different extensions disabled (in IE go to Tools|Manage Add-Ons|Toolbars and Extensions). There are also other factors that can lead to different user experiences for a particular download but based on the screenshots I believe this is the issue.

**Solution**:
If the HTTP server responds with the `content-disposition: attachment` header you should always get the gold bar prompt at the bottom.

More info on the content-disposition header: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266